# Oil Cooler Bypass

Tags: engine

I am wondering here, in relation to a oil cooler bypass. I know that we have a gauge to detect the oil temperature and make the oil bypass the cooler completely if it gets too cold. My question is, if that gauge malfunctions and stop doing its job, does the oil have another bypass at the cooler to stop the viscosity to become too high? Or would it eventually clog there without a way to bypass it?
Or am I completely wrong in this one entirely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any answer about the operation of systems to bypass oil coolers will depend on the airplane you are asking about, but it seems that you are worrying about something that just isn't a problem.

It is unlikely that any oil cooler could be so efficient as to cool the oil into a thick sludge that stops circulating.  It just isn't that thick to begin with, and the engine provides plenty of heat so you probably want the default mode to be through the oil cooler.

Comment: That is a fair point. Following that line of thought, I also do belive the bypass would be implemented based on pressure instead of temperature itself. I was wondering because I have learned that there are certain coolers that would check the oil temperature to decide if they should divert the oil instead of allowing it to continuously passing through the cooler getting more and more cold. But I also understand your statement. Would have to be a hell of a descent and prolonged time to allow oil to reach that state, maybe. 
I do tend to overthink things. Thank you for your answer!